# Regexp date in format "10-MAY-2005" javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regexp for matching date in format "10-MAY-2005" using javascript.

Comment: Why regex? Do you want to validate months with 30/31 days and leap years?

Comment: -1 because you can search on google "javascript regex date YYYY-MMM-DD" and the first result seems to be good.

Comment: **Don't** edit your question like this. Questions here are supposed to help other people too. But that does not work if you deface your question like this. If you got a helpful answer, accept it. If you solved the problem on your own, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\-] (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[\-]\d{4}$
```

And that works for me

Comment: So how do you prevent 31st February etc.?

Answer (score 2):

```
var regExp = /[0-9]{2}-JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER-[0-9]{4}/g;
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what for? And how shall you return points that I spent my time on?

Comment: @Ashwin: That's not evident from the example.

Comment: @FelixKling Never mind. I see that the OP has changed his question to something totally different. Not sure what's going on, I thought I had seen this one as the accepted answer too... I can't be dreaming all this :P

Comment: You surely noticed! He unchecked my answer which was marked as "right". I consider, his behaviour is unfair and deserves "-1".